# Why won't my balance change?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I'm trying to have a balance go up if the function "neww" is true, and down if false. neww is a random number from 0-1:

```
 Template.result.helpers({
  'neww': function(){
    return( Session.get('number') > 0.5 ? true : false )
  }
});
```

so this should declare new true or false based on the randomly generated number right? Well, I have an if else statement like this:

```
Template.balance.events({
  'click button': function() {
    if (neww = true) {
      Session.set('bal', Session.get('bal') + 1);
    } else {
      Session.set('bal', Session.get('bal') - 1);
    }
  }
});
```

It should raise my balance 1 if the number is greater than .5 and lower it otherwise.

My entire code is:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // counter starts at 0
  Session.setDefault('number', Random.fraction());
  Session.setDefault('word', "");
  Session.setDefault('bal', 5000);


  Template.hello.helpers({
    number: function () {
      return Session.get('number');
    }
  });

    Template.balance.helpers({
    bal: function () {
      return Session.get('bal');
    }
 });
  Template.hello.helpers({
  word: function () {
    return Session.get('word');
  }
});

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {
      // increment the counter when button is clicked
      Session.set("number", 0+Random.fraction());
    }

  });

 Template.result.helpers({
  'neww': function(){
    return( Session.get('number') > 0.5 ? true : false )
  }
});

Template.balance.events({
  'click button': function() {
    if (neww = true) {
      Session.set('bal', Session.get('bal') + 1);
    } else {
      Session.set('bal', Session.get('bal') - 1);
    }
  }
});

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`neww`, like all helpers, is only available within your templates themselves. If you want to use it in your JS, just make it a normal JS function and call it as normal. You can assign that function to a helper as well if you want to use it in templates too.

At present, `neww` will be undefined in the context you're trying to use it, so you should see errors in your console when you click the button. The function will throw before it actually does anything, which is why nothing's happening to the balance.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is not the correct syntax for if

   if (neww = true)
2. `neww` is not variable, it is a helper, thus you cannot make it in the if like that. In order to let `neww` is available on the `balance` template, you need to save it into a global variable like `Session`

I know that you are new to coding, therefore, learn about basic programming first. Working with frameworks like `meteor` straight away will make you feel bored gradually

Comment: Where should i start?

Comment: Depend on your background. But it is not hard to learn IT these days, rite ? https://www.coursera.org/browse/computer-science?languages=en then https://www.coursera.org/learn/meteor-development

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can fix the code to make it do what you want:

```
Template.balance.events({
  'click button': function() {
    if ( Session.get('number') > 0.5 ) {
      Session.set('bal', Session.get('bal') + 1);
    } else {
      Session.set('bal', Session.get('bal') - 1);
    }
  }
});
```

You can completely get rid of your `neww` helper.  To read more about how template helpers, events, and sessions work, checkout the [Meteor Guide](http://guide.meteor.com).